# Where to get analysts' earnings estimates data?

Tags: estimation, earnings

I know [thomsonreuters](http://thomsonreuters.com/estimates/) provide analysts' earnings estimates data. Is there any sources I could get it for free?

For example, [this website](http://www.analystratings.net/stocks/NYSE/AEO/) has analysts' earnings data. What's the source of this and how to import to my own DB?

Comment: We have a global question for all data-related issues.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, your local universities/college have bloomberg computers as part of their business section.  They are especially useful as the function *ANR* provides all available/current and historical recommendations from each firm and it's available to be exported to excel.